# How to query ravendb by pre-filter and normalized reference?

Tags: c#, .net, indexing, ravendb

I have a ravendb query, and it is resulting in the error "The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value." from the ravendb server.  I know that it is because dingerIds (local var) has way too many values in it.

The query looks something like this:

```
...
// raven is an open document session

var hums = (from hum in raven.Query<Hum>()
            where hum.Dingers.Any(dinger => dinger.Status.In(x, y, z))
            select hum).ToList();

var dingerIds = (from hum in hums
             from dinger in hum.Dingers
             where dinger.Status.In(x, y, z)
             select dinger.Id).ToList();

var zips = raven.Query<Zip>().
       Where(zip => zip.DingerIds.Any(dingerId => dingerId.In(dingerIds))).
       ToList();
```

Here are the involved classes and properties for reference. The organization of the types is probably not ideal but it's what I'm stuck with:

```
class Hum { List<Dinger> Dingers {get;set;} ... }
class Dinger { string Id {get;set;} ... } // Id is a homespun unique Id
class Zip { List<string> DingerIds {get;set;} ... }
```

To fix the problem, I thought a live projection was the answer and I started trying to write an AbstractIndexCreationTask with a Map and TransformResult (knowing that it will need to be updated to an AbstractTransformerCreationTask when we upgrade to 2.5).  Here's how far I got, obviously not that far:

```
Map = hums => 
    from hum in hums
    from dinger in hum.Dingers
    where dinger.Status.In(x, y, z)
    select new { dinger.Id };

TransformResults = (database, hums) =>
    from hum in hums
    from dinger in hum.Dingers
    let zip = database.  // ?? where to go from here
```

Perhaps I am going about this wrong.  Can this be done in an index?  And, for an extra tidbit for all of us still learning ravendb, is it possible to do it inline without making the query string too long?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to use a relational model with Raven. It won't work, and you'll end up having much more problems.

To solve the specific problem you mentioned you can use Lazy operations, which will force the request to be sent as a POST.

But again, I'd highly recommend redesigning the model so it fits a document database.

Comment: So you're saying that I absolutely must redesign the model in order to fix this? And that it is impossible to create an index that does this?  A redesign is not an option for me.

Comment: It seems like it, yes. Without understanding the actual use cases its hard to know, but the scenario you're describing is usually what we see in a relational model trying to be enforced on a document database

Comment: Yeah, I believe/agree with that. Unfortunately, this is the state of things in a fully developed application. Thanks.

Comment: +1. @Sean, try to convince your team/managers that they are trying to fit square pegs through round holes. You're likely to get into painful situations by misusing a tool like this. Actually, Itamar has a great talk on the topic of designing RavenDB documents that could be helpful for you: http://vimeo.com/43659005